# LaTeX code for arrow

Tags: diagrams, chemistry

What is the LaTeX code for this kind of arrow:

[image: Double Arrow from A to B and C]

These are useful in chemical kinetics and parallel reactions...

---

Also how to draw arrows for redox reactions?

[image: Redox arrows]

I mean those arrows above and below...

---

(here i drew it using MS-Word!)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/

Comment: @Sigur Thanks but any idea of the first one?

Comment: Maybe http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/marketing-distribution-channel/ or in general http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/

Comment: **Any** of the LaTeX-friendly drawing tools could do the first one, even a simple `picture` environment with a couple of `\line`s and `\vector`s.  But it's hard to recommend an appropriate solution without some idea of what you would prefer to use.  If the context is chemistry then you should probably get to grips with [`chemfig`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132386/forked-arrows-with-chemfig)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redox reactions can be typeset using the `chemmacros` package. The manual has a number of examples. Here is a quick try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{
  "\OX{o1,Zn}" \sld{} + "\OX{r1,Cu}" {}^2+ \aq
  ->
  "\OX{r2,Cu}" \sld{} + "\OX{o2,Zn}" {}^2+ \aq
}
\redox(o1,o2)[->]{\small oxidation (2 electrons lost)}
\redox(r1,r2)[->][-1]{\small reduction (2 electrons gained)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first question is answered here: [Forked arrows with chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132386/)