# Forked arrows with chemfig and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, chemfig

this question has been asked in this link: [Forked arrows with chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132386/forked-arrows-with-chemfig)
It is very helpful for me. I would like to thank Gonzalo Medina for his solution. 
However, I have two questions that I cannot find any solution anywhere.

1) How to make \chemfig    work properly inside tikzpicture? 
I want to have a chemical structure (which is drawn by chemfig) above and below the arrow. However when I use `\chemfig{...}` all the bonds turn to arrow. I think it is because this command stays inside the `\draw` command.

2) How can I change the length of only the arrow part (the line still the same) to fit the content of the node above/ below the arrow.

Here is the scheme I want to make: [image]

Thanks a ton!

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt,10pt]{standalone}%[a4paper]
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm and 2cm]
    %\tikzset{myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, thick},mylabel/.style={text width=7em, text centered} }  
\setcrambond{4pt}{}{}
%\setarrowoffset{10pt}
\node (A)
{\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]HO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]OH)>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off  2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
%===================================
\node [above right= of A](B)
{\hspace{2cm}\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-90,0.5]-[:-130,0.5](-[:-80,0.6]\chemabove{O}{\hspace{4mm}\scriptstyle\ominus})=[:160,0.6]O))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
%===================================
\node[below=of B, align=left](B1){R=H or \ch{CH2COONa} \\depending on DS}; %align=left to use \\ inside node
%===================================
\node[below=0.5 of B1](C)
{\hspace{2cm}\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-120,0.5]-[:-60,0.5](-[,0.4]OR)-[:-120,0.5]-[:-60,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{4mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}}; %{(} or {)} for sth like N(CH3)3Cl inside chemfig 
%===================================
\node[below=of C, align=left](C1)
{\hspace{1cm} R=H, \chemfig{-[:30,0.5](-[:90,0.4]OR)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}\\ \hspace{1.1cm}depending on MS};
%===================================
\node[below=0.5 of C1](D)
{\hspace{2cm}\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-30,0.6]SO_3Na))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off    2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
%===================================
\node[below=of D](D1)
{R=H, \ch{SO3Na}};
%===================================
\node[below=0.5 of D1](E)
{\hspace{3cm}\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
%===================================
\node[below=of E](E1)
{R=H, \chemfig{(=[:90,0.4]O)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}};
%\draw[myarrow] (A.east) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0,1) |-(B.west);    
%===================================
\draw[-stealth](A) --($(A.0)!0.5!(B.west|-A.0)$) |- (B.west) node[above]{\ch{ClCH2COONa}}node[below,align=left]{aq. \ch{NaOH}\\slurry medium};
%===================================
\draw[-stealth](A) -- ($(A.0)!0.5!(C.west|-A.0)$) |- (C.west) node[above]{\chemfig{?-[:90,0.5]O-[:-30,0.5]?-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}} node[below,align=left]{aq. \ch{NaOH}\\slurry medium};
%===================================
\draw[-stealth](A) -- ($(A.0)!0.5!(D.west|-A.0)$) |- (D.west) node[above,align=left]{(i) \ch{SO3}.DMF or \ch{SO3}.pyridine\\(DMF/LiCl) 50 \si{\degreeCelsius})}node[below,align=left]{(ii) \ch{NaOH}};
%===================================
\draw[-stealth](A) -- ($(A.0)!0.5!(E.west|-A.0)$) |- (E.west) node[above,align=left]{\chemfig{HO-[:30,0.5](=[:90,0.4]O)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}}node[below,align=left]{DMSO, CDI \\ 20 h, 70 \si{\degreeCelsius}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please mark your code with four spaces as code to make it readable.

Comment: Your code does not compile, I'm getting 12 errors, please make sure it's compilable.

Comment: @Carina: sorry I don't understand. what do you mean by saying "four spaces"?

Comment: @Alenanno: yes it is compilable. I added a picture of the scheme I want to make, so it might be easier to see.

Comment: @ChungNguyen It's ok, it was already edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forked arrows with chemfig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132386/forked-arrows-with-chemfig)

Comment: @StefanPinnow: it is the same topic but my questions are different. I could not figure it out with the previous link

Comment: @Alenanno: you were right, the code did not compile alone. I ran it from my main tex file. Really sorry for my first comment. I have corrected it and now it can compile. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To 1) Here you simply need to add the optional argument `[-]` to the `\chemfig` command to "remove" the arrow heads from the "draw line" command.

To 2) Here I suggest to do that "manually". First place the top most node by using the `=<number>cm and <number>cm of <node>` feature, then decide with the created `\split` variable where the path to this node should be "split" and decide with the created `\xshift` variable the offset of the nodes placed above and below the arrow. While drawing the reaction scheme you can simply adjust the node positions on the right and/or by adjusting the `\split` ratio to fit your needs.

Here is a simplyfied reaction scheme as demonstration for the above said.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \setcrambond{4pt}{}{}
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xshift}{1cm}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\split}{0.1}

        \node (A) {A};
        \node [above right=2cm and 5cm of A](B) {B};

        \draw[-stealth](A) --($(A.0)!\split!(B.west|-A.0)$) |- (B.west)
                % just to show the alignment point for the following nodes
                coordinate [pos=0.5,xshift=\xshift] (test)
            node [pos=0.5,xshift=\xshift,above,anchor=south west]
                {\ch{ClCH2COONa}}
            node [pos=0.5,xshift=\xshift,below,anchor=north west]
                {\chemfig[-]{?-[:90,0.5]O-[:-30,0.5]?-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}};
                % show the alignment points
                \fill [red] (test) circle (2pt) -- +(-1cm,0) circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing result of simplified reaction scheme code]

---

And here you can find your full reaction scheme, where I in addition have cleaned up some non-necessary `\hspace`s and set proper alignments of the nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=stealth,
        shorten >=1mm,
        component node/.style={
            % keys for `\chemfig'
            -,
            shorten >=0pt,
%            % fill the nodes (useful for debugging)
%            fill=red!50,
        },
        arrow node/.style={
            pos=0.5,
            xshift=\xshift,
            align=left,
            % keys for `\chemfig'
            -,
            shorten >=0pt,
        },
    ]
            \setcrambond{4pt}{}{}
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xshift}{1mm}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\split}{0.1}

    % left side of reaction scheme
        \node [component node] (A)
            {\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]HO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]OH)>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off  2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};

    % right side of reaction scheme
        \node [component node,above right=2cm and 6cm of A] (B)
            {\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-90,0.5]-[:-130,0.5](-[:-80,0.6]\chemabove{O}{\hspace{4mm}\scriptstyle\ominus})=[:160,0.6]O))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
        \node [component node,below=0 of B.south west,anchor=north west,align=left] (B1)
            {R=H or \ch{CH2COONa} \\ depending on DS}; %align=left to use \\ inside node

        \node [component node,below=0.5 of B1.south west,anchor=north west] (C)
            {\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-120,0.5]-[:-60,0.5](-[,0.4]OR)-[:-120,0.5]-[:-60,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{4mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}}; %{(} or {)} for sth like N(CH3)3Cl inside chemfig
        \node [component node,below=0 of C.south west,anchor=north west, align=left](C1)
            {R=H, \chemfig{-[:30,0.5](-[:90,0.4]OR)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}\\ \hspace{1.1cm}depending on MS};

        \node [component node,below=0.5 of C1.south west,anchor=north west](D)
            {\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-30,0.6]SO_3Na))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off    2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
        \node [component node,below=0 of D.south west,anchor=north west] (D1)
            {R=H, \ch{SO3Na}};

        \node [component node,below=0.5 of D1.south west,anchor=north west] (E)
            {\chemfig{-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt]O-[:15,0.5]?[A]<[:-60](-[:165,0.6]RO)-[:15,,,,line width = 4pt](-[:-60,0.6]O(-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}))>[:-15](-[:15,0.5]O-[:-15,0.5,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])-[:120]O-[:-165]?[A]}};
        \node [component node,below=0 of E.south west,anchor=north west](E1)
            {R=H, \chemfig{(=[:90,0.4]O)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}};

    % draw reaction arrows + nodes
        %\draw[myarrow] (A.east) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0,1) |-(B.west);
        \draw [->] (A) -- ($(A.east)!\split!(B.west|-A.east)$) |- (B.west)
            node [arrow node,above right]
                {\ch{ClCH2COONa}}
            node [arrow node,below right]
                {aq. \ch{NaOH}\\slurry medium};
        \draw [->] (A) -- ($(A.east)!\split!(C.west|-A.east)$) |- (C.west)
            node [arrow node,above right]
                {\chemfig[-]{?-[:90,0.5]O-[:-30,0.5]?-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}}
            node [arrow node,below right]
                {aq. \ch{NaOH} \\ slurry medium};
        \draw [->] (A) -- ($(A.east)!\split!(D.west|-A.east)$) |- (D.west)
            node [arrow node,above right]
                {(i) \ch{SO3}.DMF or \ch{SO3}.pyridine\\(DMF/LiCl) \SI{50}{\degreeCelsius})}
            node [arrow node,below right]
                {(ii) \ch{NaOH}};
        \draw [->] (A) -- ($(A.east)!\split!(E.west|-A.east)$) |- (E.west)
            node [arrow node,above right]
                {\chemfig[-]{HO-[:30,0.5](=[:90,0.4]O)-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.5]-[:-30,0.5]-[:30,0.6]\chemabove{N}{\hspace{-5mm}\scriptstyle\oplus}{(}CH_3{)}_3\chemabove{Cl}{\hspace{5mm}\scriptstyle\ominus}}}
            node [arrow node,below right]
                {DMSO, CDI \\ \SI{20}{\hour}, \SI{70}{\degreeCelsius}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing result of full reaction scheme]

Comment: wow..what a wonderful work. It looks quite complicated for me...but I will definitely learn from it. Thank you thousand times. Just wanna add something here. I didn't know that the number between (..) in the code: $...$ was to specify the point for splitting as well. So, I just figured out how to adjust the length of the arrow part as I mentioned in my second question. Thanks thanks thanks :-)

Comment: @Chung, you are welcome. I think "my work" was the easy part of the picture. I would have never been able to draw the `\chemfig`s.    What really helps to figure out how `tikz` works is to do and _understand_ the first tutorials in the pgf manual (sections 2 to 5, if you don't need mindmaps). Maybe you have to do them twice, but there will come the time it makes "click" and you'll have a really good understanding what is going on and how to achieve stuff.

Comment: you are right. I will definitely read and practice the instruction. By the way, it is really fun to play with chemfig. I am getting better in drawing chemical structures and really happy about that. I hope that I can help you later :-) Thanks again..I wish I could vote for more than 1 time :D