# Want to make the following forked arrows using mhchem and chemfig and arrow

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, mhchem

[image]

I have a figure which i want to do using `mhchem` and `chemfig` package. Is it possible to make forked arrows using `mhchem`/`chemfig`? Please help. I do not have any MWE created for this sort of figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{mychemistry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=-(-[:-30]C{(}CH_3{)}_3)=-(-[:90]OH)=-)}}{Z}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not? Please add as always  a MWE.

Comment: What do you mean a MWE ? As i understand it means minimum working example. But, i dont have a MWE for this. I can make only the benzene figure, after that I cannot proceed, as I am not sure how  to proceed.

Comment: Ok, make that..

Comment: Here I have added the MWE to my original question. I have currently only made the benzene figure. Please help me draw onwards from here

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294287/117534 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132412/117534

Comment: Also, please consider [accepting answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/117534) to your previous questions if you are satisfied with them -- that's the preferred way to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Please *do not use* the `mychemistry` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{mychemistry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (benzine) at (0,0) {\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=-(-[:-30]C{(}CH_3{)}_3)=-(-[:90]OH)=-)}}{$Z$}};
    \coordinate (a) at ($(benzine.east)+(1,0)$);

    \draw[] ($(benzine)!0.5!(benzine.east)$) -- node[above]{$X_2$} (a);
    \draw[->] (a) |-++ (1,1) node[right,text width=6cm]{
        monohalo substututed derivative\\
        when $X_2$ = \ch{I_2}
    };
    \draw[->] (a) --++ (1,0) node[right,text width=6cm]{
        dihalo substututed derivative\\
        when $X_2$ = \ch{Br_2}
    };
    \draw[->] (a) |-++ (1,-1) node[right,text width=6cm]{
        trihalo substututed derivative\\
        when $X_2$ = \ch{Cl_2}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tikz` need not be loaded because `chemfig` already loads it. And the halogens should be typeset using `ch{}` (since `chemmacros` is loaded).

Comment: `Z`is still misplaced. And the `X` could be italic (because it's a variable/placeholder).

Comment: The `Z` is placed by the given code, so I didn't changed that, because the question is mainly about the forked arrow. But feel free to edit the code...

Comment: @Troy you can configure `chemmacros` to use `mhchem` so the statement about `\ch` is not *entirely* true… :)

Comment: Yes the above working is excellent, thanks. This solves my issue, also what i need to do to get the Z at the centre of the ring? Like that in image i had pasted earlier. What should i use?