# How can I write this chemical equation?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How can I write this chemical equation, especially the arrows? [image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\begin{document} 
\schemestart \chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2CH_2-OH} \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]} \chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-H} \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]} \chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-OH} 
\schemestop 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Can you provide some code of what you have tried so far. Do you know [chemfig](https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) for drawing chemical equations?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig} 

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2CH_2-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]} 
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]}
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\schemestop

\end{document}

Comment: But I need to draw square arrow as in picture to fit margins in my box

Comment: Looks like you can do it  with tikz. See here for a similar example, which you can adjust to your needs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294222/forked-arrows-with-chemfig-and-tikzpicture . Or take this one, which apperas to be less code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132386/forked-arrows-with-chemfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternatives that use the abbreviation *n*Pr for the *n*-propyl group. With this abbreviation (and shorter bond lengths) you should be able to fit both oxidation reactions next to each other in the textwidth of a standard `article` document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2.25em}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\schemestart
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-CH_2-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[\ch{K2Cr2O7}, \ch{H+}]}[,1.8]
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-C(=[2]O)-H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[[O]]}
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\schemestop
\bigskip

\noindent
\schemestart
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-CH_2-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[\ch{K2Cr2O7}, \ch{H+}]}[,1.8]
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-[:30]C(=[2]O)-[:-30]H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[[O]]}
\chemfig{\textit{n}Pr-[:30]C(=[2]O)-[:-30]OH}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, leandriis:

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\definesubmol\I{\vphantom{C}}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3|!\I-CH_2|!\I-CH_2|!\I-CH_2|!\I(=[2,,,,draw=none]\vphantom{O})-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
    {->[ \footnotesize\chemfig{K_2Cr_2O_7}/\chemfig{H^{+}} ]}[,1.6]
\chemfig{CH_3|!\I-CH_2|!\I-CH_2|!\I-C|!\I(=[2]O)
    -@{h3}H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid east){0}[-90,2]
\chemfig{CH_3|!\I-CH_2|!\I-CH_2|!\I-C(=[2]O)-O@{h4}H}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt]
    (h3) -- ([xshift=25pt]h3.center) -- node[pos=0.5,right] {\footnotesize [O]} ([xshift=25pt]h4.center) -- (h4);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Polyn.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig} 

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2CH_2-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]} 
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[O]}
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH_2-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0]{Simplified Arabic}
\newcommand{\en}{\textenglish}
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-OH}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
    {->[ \footnotesize\chemfig{K_2Cr_2O_7}/\chemfig{H^{+}} ]}[,1.6]
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)
        -@{h3}H}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid east){0}[-90,2]
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)-O@{h4}H}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt]
        (h3) -- ([xshift=25pt]h3.center) -- node[pos=0.5,right] {\footnotesize [O]} ([xshift=25pt]h4.center) -- (h4);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use this code in texstudio to write Arabic text it give me this results (mean arrows) as in picture.