# What is the suitable package to write a chemical chain reaction?

Tags: chemistry

I want to know the suitable package for and example of realization.

[image]

Comment: This should be doable with the `chemfig` package.

Comment: This might be of interest here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132386/

Comment: @clemens In your link chemical equations was made by means  both chemfig and tikz. It is possible to do it by  means only one chemical package?

Comment: `chemfig` uses TikZ itself so if you use `chemfig` you automatically use TikZ. On the other hand you can get every `chemfig` formula/scheme with pure TikZ – but with significantly more effort.

Comment: Other than that: have a look at XyMTeX.